# When Selenium IDE converts html into php, why doesn't it create simple Selenese commands?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-ide

I am using:

- Selenium IDE version: 1.0.10
- PHPUnit 3.4.15

If I use Selenium IDE (the firefox plugin) to create a very simple test case, with one command in a *Selenese table row*:

```
waitForElementPresent | css=div
```

Then use the `Selenium IDE > Options > Format > PHP` feature to convert that code into PHP.

I get something like:

```
<?php    
...    
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  ...
        for ($second = 0; ; $second++) {
                if ($second >= 60) $this->fail("timeout");
                try {
                        if ($this->isElementPresent("css=div")) break;
                } catch (Exception $e) {}
                sleep(1);
 ...
}
```

My question is:

Why is that PHP code generated in such a convoluted way?

I could convert that command into something like:

```
<?php    
...    
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  ...
        $this->waitForElementPresent("css=div");
 ...
}
```

The latter line of php would make use of the magic method in the parent class: `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::__call($command, $arguments)`

What is the reasoning behind this kind of convoluted PHP output?

- Is it just to make the PHP less reliant on PHPUnit?
- Is it because it is a patch on a bug?
- Is it because it gives better test result feedback?

I'm asking because I am a selenium newbie and am wondering whether there is any reason why I should not just write my methods in the selenese-style of that second code example (above).

Answer (score 1):

All those are written because of bugs that will occur in:

```
$this->waitForElementPresent("css=div");
```

For instance selenium's code have a timeout among lot of other things...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on this. Which Selenium component has the waitForElementPresent() bug: Selenium Server, Core, Browser, PHPUnit?  One of the reason's why I started to make use of  $this->waitForElementPresent() was because i noticed that $this->setTimeout() was having no effect.

Comment: It does not have a bug, it will just wait... What if element never exists? the above code will wait indefinitely. But with the longer version you have control over how much time you wait for it. And that is 60 seconds in the long code.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that the PHPUnit's [`$this->setTimeout()`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html) method would prevent it from waiting infinitely during a call to `$this->waitForElementPresent`.